# word not in vocabulary

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec

First time using `word2vec` and the file I am working with is in `XML` format. I want to iterate through the patents to find each Title then apply `word2vec` to see if there are similar words(to indicate similar titles).

So far I have parsed the XML file using Element tree to retrieve each title, then I have applied `sent_tokenizer` followed by tweet `tokenizer` to return a list of sentences where each word has been tokenized (not sure if this was the best method). I then put the tokenized sentenses into my `word2vec` model and tested with one word to see if it returned a vector. This seems to only work for a word in the first sentence. I'm not sure it is recognising all the sentences?

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import gensim
    import nltk
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer, sent_tokenize

    tree = ET.parse('6785.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    for child in root.iter("Title"):
        Patent_Title = child.text
        sentence = Patent_Title
        stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
        tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence)
        print(tokens)

        tokenizer_words = TweetTokenizer()
        tokens_sentences = [tokenizer_words.tokenize(t) for t in tokens]
        #print(tokens_sentences)

        model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(tokens_sentences, min_count=1,size=32)
        words = list(model.wv.vocab)
        print(words)
        print(model['Solar'])
```

I would expect it to identify the word 'solar' in a sentence and print out the vector then I could look for similar words. I am receiving the `error`:

word 'Solar' not in vocabulary"

Comment: what does look like 6785.xml ?

Comment: It was taken from https://www.ipo.gov.uk/pro-types/pro-patent/pro-p-os/pro-p-journal/p-pj-download.htm  - I clicked Basic XML and hit download

Comment: thx. For now I get "Resource stopwords not found."

Comment: Sorry you need to download, if you write nltk.download() it will open available packages and you can select stopwords and click download then it should work with from nltk.corpus import stopwords

Comment: pip3 install nltk

nltk.download('stopwords')

nltk.download('punkt')


ok I'm here `KeyError: "word 'Solar' not in vocabulary"`

Comment: nevermind, on my side your code seems to work. In the sample you gave me was the word laser `<Title>Improvements in or relating to laser marking</Title>`, thus I suppy "laser" with `print(model['laser'])` and I got correct answer (I guess)

Comment: ['Improvements', 'or', 'in', 'to', 'laser', 'marking', 'relating']
[-0.00959895 -0.01433809 -0.00210128  0.01251747  0.00031919 -0.01034923
 -0.00066724  0.00769976  0.00542362 -0.00203011  0.00617265 -0.00034118
  0.01314736  0.00434213 -0.00652452  0.00298504  0.01202446  0.00770366
 -0.00320959 -0.00655512 -0.00676045 -0.01482045 -0.00300813  0.00949095
 -0.00036619 -0.01077708 -0.01547267 -0.00225088  0.01108087  0.00422871
 -0.00890174  0.0012026 ]

Comment: yes that is what I get and that is only for the first title which doesn't have the word solar

Comment: then it is just about handling error on the first occurences of the loop

Comment: try:
        print(model['Solar'])
    except Exception as e:
        pass

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the errors as exceptions on first loop occurence.

```
# print(model['Solar'])
try:
    print(model['Solar'])
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Working code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gensim
import nltk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer, sent_tokenize

tree = ET.parse('6785.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.iter("Title"):
    Patent_Title = child.text
    sentence = Patent_Title
    stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence)
    print(tokens)

    tokenizer_words = TweetTokenizer()
    tokens_sentences = [tokenizer_words.tokenize(t) for t in tokens]
    #print(tokens_sentences)

    model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(tokens_sentences, min_count=1,size=32)
    words = list(model.wv.vocab)
    print(words)
    try:
        print(model['Solar'])
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Comment: There is <Title>Solar energy simiulation</Title>

Comment: Thanks, that returned all my titles and the vector under the word title. print(model['Radiotherapy']) output >  ['Radiotherapy devices and access authorisation']
[-0.01113974  0.00639009  0.00976604 -0.004333    0.00290035  0.00248319
 -0.00760938 -0.01228361 -0.01197472 -0.00614711 -0.01064915 -0.00693584
 -0.00337423  0.00065452  0.00834927  0.01391384 -0.00741098 -0.00160623
  0.01534168  0.00119743  0.01381986 -0.00495988  0.01196167 -0.01401392
 -0.01012376 -0.00070101 -0.00630556  0.0031876   0.00303052 -0.01282678. Are you able to run model.most_similar(positive=[WORD], topn=N) ?

Comment: I expect WORD="Solar" but what is topn?

Comment: result = model.most_similar("solar") print(result)?

Comment: sentences = ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".split(), 
             "The sun is shining bright".split()] model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences,min_count=1,size=32)
words = list(model.wv.vocab)
#print(model["quick"])
result = model.most_similar("fox")
print(result)

Comment: import gensim
sentences = ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".split(), 
        "The sun is shining bright".split()] 
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences,min_count=1,size=32) 
words = list(model.wv.vocab) 
#print(model["quick"]) 
result = model.most_similar("fox") 
print(result)

Comment: [('shining', 0.293942391872406), ('The', 0.2876792550086975), ('over', 0.2617454528808594), ('quick', 0.25567924976348877), ('the', 0.22210019826889038), ('sun', 0.19922079145908356), ('lazy', 0.16388347744941711), ('is', -0.05428565293550491), ('dog', -0.10405820608139038), ('brown', -0.13440746068954468)]

Comment: it is meant to return words and vectors with similarity but I still get the word not in vocabulary error. I'm not sure if I had to split somewhere like the sentences example above so I can use my model

Comment: Does it work for you using my model? (the fox one is an example of how it should output)

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because `Solar` is not in your corpus.

`Word2Vec` tries to generate word vectors for each word **in** your `tokens_sentences`. If the training corpus  didn't include the word/token that you try to look up, word2vec would not have the word vector for that word and that is why you got an error.

Advice: try to make your text data case-insensitive. That is, make all the text lower case (upper case works too but not the convention.)